# Angular - Primeng's confirmDialog is shown behind the ng-bootstrap's modal

Tags: html, angular, npm, primeng, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the primeng and ng-bootstrap components to make a website with angular.

To capture information I use a form within an ng-bootstrap modal. When clicking on the "save" button of that modal The primeng confirmDialog should appear. The problem is that it appears behind the modal.

How can I fix it?

Here's some of my HTML:

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="pi pi-exclamation-triangle" width="425" appendTo="body"></p-confirmDialog>

<ng-template #modalFormOrder let-c="close" let-d="dismiss" id="modalFormOrder">
    <div class="modal-header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn m-btn--pill m-btn--air btn-success" (click)="SaveEditLoadOrder()">Save</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm somehow sure that both dialogs use z-index CSS property
Override the z-index CSS property with a bigger number for the element that you want to appears first, example  z-index: 1001;

If you want to override Css for PrimeNG I suggest you write it on /src/styles.css . Following Example is overriding calendar CSS

```
 .ui-calendar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

On PrimeNG documentation you can find the CSS classes to override for each component